# How can I check if two variables are true?

Tags: php

How can I check if two variables are true - either one can be true, I've tried:

```
    if($width || $height)
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Either one can be true? Can they also both be true?

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error message? Did you get incorrect results? Did you get *no results*? If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect? What were you expecting instead? Did you get *any* correct results? If so, what were they? Don't make us guess.

Comment: This is correct code for boolean or, your error must be elsewhere or your assumption about $width and $height is wrong. Anyway who the hell checks such vars for a boolean expression? I would expect them to be integers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want either to be "truthy" (loosely equal to `true`), the syntax you have works.

If you want one to be literally a boolean `true`, you need the type-sensitive comparison:

```
if($width === true || $height === true)
```

Likewise, to check if both are truthy:

```
if($width && $height)
```

or both literally `true`:

```
if($width === true && $height === true)
```

You may want to read [**the documentation about the PHP `==` and `===` operators**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to use the `&&` operator:

```
if($width && $height)
```

**Further Reading**

- [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)